# Load all Fixtures files in symfony2 console

Tags: symfony, heroku, console, doctrine, fixtures

I am facing a strain behaviour on the console of symfony2 . I have a local envinroment and if I execute:

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

> purging database
>   loading Application\Sonata\UserBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUserData
>   loading ApplicationNewsBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadAdvertisementData
>   loading ApplicationNewsBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadArticleData
>   loading ApplicationNewsBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadLiveBlogData
>   loading ApplicationNewsBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadVideoData

I upload the code to Heroku ( the same code) and I execute the same command but I only execute the two first fixtures:

> purging database
>
> loading Application\Sonata\UserBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUserData
>   loading ApplicationNewsBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadAdvertisementData

At this point, I suppose that is something related with the configuration, and I also executed the command on dev enviroment, but with the same result.

```
php app/console --env=dev doctrine:fixtures:load
```

I am using symfony 2.6.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the path, the name of the folder is DataFIxtures with I in capital letter, it seems that is not a problem working with vagrant in local but when I use heroku container doesn't understand this path and it doesn't execute the command. Changing the name the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 obvious reasons why you may be experiencing this behavior:

1. **Wrong File Permissions** on the remote system

   Check wether all the fixture files are readable by the user invoking the 
   PHP process otherwise they may not be found and therefore not be loaded.
2. **Outdated composer Autoloader**

   If you have dumped an optimized autoloader with `-a` / `--classmap-authoritative` or `--apcu` and you've deployed a new version with new fixture classes afterwards ... the new classes may not be in the classmap yet and aren't autoloaded. To fix this issue just dump the autoloader again by running `composer dump-autoload -a`.